# Transform line by line text file into tab delimited format by checking header by python

Tags: python

I have a large text file of experimental data like

```
spectrum:
 index: 1
 mz: 4544.5445
 intensity: 57875100000
 type: 1
 something: skip
 params - m1
 binary: [4] 1 2 3 4 
 params - int1
 binary: [4] 11 22 33 44
spectrum:
 index: 2
 mz: 546.7777
 intensity: 210009
 type: 2
 params - m2
 binary: [4] 2 3 4 5 
 params - int2
 binary: [4] 55 44 33 22
 charge: 3
 others: no need to put into column
spectrum:
 index: 3
```

I want to print it out as csv file, information in each spectrum data are put in the same row regarding its header. If they don't have the information in that header, just skip (or put NA in) it. If they have more than one value, print each next line.

Is there some easy ways by python to get the result like this?
[image]

Comment: Sure, just do it. Read one record at a time, write each record out to a csv file as you go. You didn't post any code indicating a problem, so it looks like you have not put in any effort, and have not gotten stuck. So just do it.

Comment: Your column names are not consistently ordered and have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like that:

PSEYDOCODE

```
class Spectrum():
    def add(self, text):
        column, value = text.split(' ')
        if column == 'index:'
            self._csv['index'] = int(value)
        elif column == 'mz:'
            self._csv['mz'] = float(value)
        ... an so on

spectrum = Spectrum()
with text file as in_file
  for line in in_file
     if line == 'spectrum:'
        if  in_spectrum
            spectrum.expand_to_csv()
            spectrum = Spectrum()
        in_spectrum = True
        continue

     spectrum.add(line)
```